# Close The Modal Dialog Of A Provider-Hosted App

Tags: javascript, csom, provider-hosted-app, popup, close

I have a provider hosted app which creating a custom ECB and Ribbon action  on lists in SPO which opens popup using the   `newcustomaAction.Url = "javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('" + Actionurl + "', RefreshOnDialogClose, 600, 400,'Publish')";` Now i want to close the popup using  button click on the opened popup(Aspx form). 
I tried msdn link [How To Close The Modal Dialog Of A Provider-Hosted App](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dd87ca1d-c66a-4129-9e7d-7895a6ab8750/how-to-close-the-modal-dialog-of-a-providerhosted-app?forum=appsforsharepoint) but not able to find the solutions.

Script:

```
 function closeParentDialog(refresh) {
    var target = parent.postMessage ? parent : (parent.document.postMessage ? parent.document : undefined);
    if (refresh)
        target.postMessage(‘CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh’, ‘*’);
    else
        target.postMessage(‘CloseCustomActionDialogNoRefresh’, ‘*’);
}
```

[image: popupclose]

Any Suggestions please

Comment: Anyone have solution...?